# Why won't while loops find a palindrome in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

i dont know if i am just doing this wrong, but using eclipse ill run it and enter a word but it won't return anything. i suck at coding so please help.

```
import cs1.Keyboard;
public class Palindrome 
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String w = Keyboard.readString();
        int a = 0;
        char n = w.charAt(a);
        char j = w.charAt(w.length()-1);
        while(a < j);
        {
            if (j!=n)
                System.out.println("This word isnt a palindrome... try     again.");
            if (j==n)
            {
                j--;
                a++;
            }
                System.out.println("This is a palindrome!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong in this code. I'd suggest reviewing how to write methods in java.

Comment: Even considering that the `Keyboard` class returns a String correctly, your `while` loop has a `;` after it. Remove that. Then use a debugger to test your logic

Comment: So you ignored the warning you got about an empty `while` loop? I'm sure Eclipse is able to tell you that that's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
char j = w.charAt(w.length() - a);
```

and, when incrementing a in the while loop, update the indexes

```
n = w.charAt(a);
j = w.charAt(w.length()-1);
```

Also, make sure Keyboard.readString() returns a String. Try using Scanner.